# Dell Precision 7x30 RAID setup

Tags: raid, dell-precision, nvme

I'm in receipt of a Dell precision 7730. I've installed two Samsung 970 pro NVMe SSDs, but for the life of me, I cannot work out how to set the drives up in a RAID 1 configuration and Google is not my friend today.

It must be possible:

1. A user mentions they've done it [here](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/precision-7530-precision-7730-owners-thread.820539/page-51#post-10776548), albeit RAID 0:

> I've got 3 970 Pro 1TB drives and 2 of them are in RAID 0. There is a speed increase of a few hundred mb/s but be aware that you cannot use Samsung NVMe drivers for the drives that are in the RAID array. 
>   anuraj1, Aug 5, 2018

2. It is possible to build a custom system with 2x NVMe drives and RAID 1 configuration on Dell's [website](https://www.dell.com/en-uk/work/shop/pdr/precision-17-7730-laptop/xctop7730emea?selectionState=eyJPQyI6InhjdG9wNzczMGVtZWEiLCJNb2RzIjpbeyJJZCI6OCwiT3B0cyI6W3siSWQiOiJHQjNROUU3In1dfSx7IklkIjo2MzcsIk9wdHMiOlt7IklkIjoiR1RMUTlSUyJ9XX0seyJJZCI6NzA1LCJPcHRzIjpbeyJJZCI6Ikc2QlRDRVoifV19LHsiSWQiOjEwMDksIk9wdHMiOlt7IklkIjoiR0dUNlFWUiJ9XX1dfQ%3D%3D&cartItemId=). AFIK, it's just a software configuration, especially as it's a no-cost option:
   [image]

There is very little mention in the BIOS pertaining to RAID and the options all appear to be for SATA and there are no other POST prompts pertaining to RAID setup.

I thought of using Storage Spaces, but only MS Surface devices can boot from Storage spaces (at the moment).

I don't think it is possible to create a RAID config in WinPE.

I've raised a ticket with Dell, but the response was absolutely no use whatsoever.

I did read somewhere about using Samsung's Magician tool, but that is no help.

I wonder if one of the Dell "Command" applications may help. I'm more used to setting up server RAID with a dedicated card and an army of tools to go with it.

If anyone can provide some guidance on how to proceed or the magic documentation link, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this scenario, it's `SSD-0` and `SSD-1`. the manual reads "SATA is configured to support RAID mode." ...either one can configure it for m.2 SSD - or setup software RAID; level 0/1 are supported.

Answer (score 0):

Although @Martin's answer got me going, for completeness, and as a reference for anyone else hitting the same issue, here are the steps I followed:

1. Enter BIOS setup (F2 during POST).
2. Navigate to Settings > System Configuration > SATA Operation.
3. Select RAID on.
4. Save changes and exit BIOS.
5. As system reboots, when you see the DELL logo, press F12.
6. The new option "Device Configuration" under "OTHER OPTIONS:" should now be present. Select "Device Configuration" and press enter.
7. Select the second menu item and create your RAID configuration.

I've now managed to find [Dell's documentation on RAID configuration](https://www.dell.com/support/article/uk/en/ukbsdt1/sln290569/raid-configuration-for-dell-precision-mobile-workstations?lang=en), but the steps are slightly different to the ones above.

HTH